# Array as a Variable Assignment in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If:
    `var x = [1, 2, 3];`
    `var y = [4, 5, 6]`;
    `var z = x;`

and then if `z[2] = y[0]`;

Why is it that `console.log(x);` is `[1, 2, 4]` and not `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: Because you're referencing the same array.

Comment: Memory references!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language#3638034

Answer (score 2):

When you do `var z = x;` you are no creating a new array, entirely separate from x, you are simply creating a reference to the original array. Hence, the change happens in both.

If you want to create a new object, you can use the new ES6 spread operator

`var z = {...x};`

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) for a more in-depth explanation of passing by reference and by value.

Comment: Thank you @bugs!  Does this work differently for non-arrays?

var a = 1;
var b = 2; 
var c = a;

c = 2;
console.log(a); = 1

Comment: Primitive types, such as strings or numbers, are indeed passed by value, so the problem you had above would not happen in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Cuz the 'z' variable is a pointer to the same array that 'x' point to.

Comment: Please explain your answer so that everyone understands. Answers with explanations are helpful and appreciated by all.

Answer (score 0):

An array in JavaScript is also an `object` and variables only hold a *`reference`* to an object, not the object itself. Thus both variables have a reference to *the same* object. So changing made through one variable reflected in other as well.

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [4, 5, 6];
var z = x;
z[2]=y[0];
console.log(x);

var w=Object.assign([],x);
w[0]=y[1];
console.log(x);
console.log(w);
```

Look at the example. If you want to change in a new variable and don't want reflected that change in original one than use `Object.assign`.